# Deleting file on sdcard on Android 4.4.x KitKat

Tags: android

I am attempting to delete a file on the sdcard on Android 4.4.x (KitKat).  From my understanding, we cannot simply invoke File.delete(...) since this is no longer supported.  We'll need to use the storage access framework.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

I have some sample code that uses the storage access framework that opens the file picker.  This part seems to work well.

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_DOCUMENT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

However, once the picker loads and when I find the file and click on it, I do not get the call back in "onActivityResult" as documented.  Instead, the picker just closes and nothing happens :(

Is there something missing?

I am trying to delete a file on the sdcard on android KitKat. Thanks!

Comment: Where does this code reside (activity? fragment? somewhere else?)? Where is `onActivityResult()` implemented (same activity? same fragment? somewhere else?)? What is the value of `OPEN_DOCUMENT_REQUEST_CODE`? FWIW, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Documents/Consumer) demonstrates the use of `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: This is in an AppCompatActivity.  Both the call "startActivityWithResult" and the "onActivityWithResult" reside in the same activity.  The request code is set to 123.  Thanks for the link.  I will give it a try.

Comment: Note that the method is `onActivityResult()`, not "onActivityWithResult". Otherwise, what you describe should be fine. The Storage Access Framework UI is supposed to close after you choose a piece of content, but your `onActivityResult()` method should be called.

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks. I just double checked.  It is "onActivityResult".

Comment: I checked the code in the link above and it seems to work fine so it must be something on my end.  I am just not sure what it could be.  The only difference seems to be the use of an "Activity" vs "Fragment".

Comment: I would not expect a problem there. Make sure that you are on the latest `appcompat-v7`, in case you are tripping over a bug that was fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I upgraded my library and that seems to have fixed it for some reason.  I am not sure how I can mark your comment as the solution so I just gave it +1.

Comment: If you remember the old version number, you might answer the question yourself, indicating that the problem was solved by updating `appcompat-v7` from X to Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, I found a solution.  For whatever reason, I updated my android support library from 23.0.1 -> 24.2.0 and it seems to have worked.  I tried looking through the release notes of the support library as well as closed issues in the Android source, but couldn't find anything related to my fix.  I guess I should just be grateful :)

Comment: One thing I wasn't able to find out was how to specify the exact file to the user instead of having the user choose.  I know which file the user would like to delete, all I need is his/her permission to delete it.  I don't need to have the user navigate the storage to find it.

Comment: Did you found the solution to delete the file from the sdcard? I have the same problem.